# Debugging Ambiguous outer join statement

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am new to MS Office Access , I am having some problems constructing the SQL view for this query . I keep getting a error : "The SQL statement could not be executed because it contains ambiguous outer join. To force one of the joins to be performed , create a seperate query which performs the first join and include that query in your SQL statement".

1) How do i create a seperate query in MS SQL view and include that query into my main SQL statement???

2) I cant understand why the error is occuring ??

```
SELECT [Table : PurchaseDetails].PurchaseID
FROM [Table: Supplier] 
LEFT JOIN ([Table : Purchase] 

LEFT JOIN ([Table : Product]

LEFT JOIN [Table : PurchaseDetails] 

ON [Table : Product].ProductID = [Table : PurchaseDetails].ProductID)

ON [Table : Purchase].PurchaseID = [Table : PurchaseDetails].PurchaseID)

ON [Table: Supplier].SupplierID = [Table :   Purchase].SupplierID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Access, but in SQL the ON command should follow the JOIN, like so:

```
SELECT [Table : PurchaseDetails].PurchaseID
FROM [Table: Supplier] 
LEFT JOIN [Table : Purchase] 
ON [Table : Purchase].PurchaseID = [Table : PurchaseDetails].PurchaseID

LEFT JOIN [Table : Product]
ON [Table : Product].ProductID = [Table : PurchaseDetails].ProductID

LEFT JOIN [Table : PurchaseDetails] 
ON [Table: Supplier].SupplierID = [Table :   Purchase].SupplierID;
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do i create a seperate query in MS SQL view and include that query into my main SQL statement?

You have a query involving multiple LEFT JOINs and the database engine cannot determine exactly how you want the tables joined. Specifically, it has determined that it will (or *could*) return different results depending on the order in which it applies the JOINs.

So, it is asking you to

- create a query using only a subset of the tables,
- save that query in Access, and then
- create another query that uses the other table(s) *and the saved query* to produce the final result.

For example, you could create the following query and save it in Access as `Purchase_PurchaseDetails`

```
SELECT Purchase.PurchaseID, Purchase.SupplierID
FROM Purchase LEFT JOIN PurchaseDetails
    ON Purchase.PurchaseID=PurchaseDetails.PurchaseID
```

Then you could use that query in *another* query, e.g.,

```
SELECT Supplier.SupplierID
FROM Suppliers LEFT JOIN Purchase_PurchaseDetails
    ON Supplier.SupplierID=Purchase_PurchaseDetails.SupplierID
```

...or something along those lines.

Comment: How do i save the query as Purchase_PurchaseDetails

Comment: @user2284926 In Access, choose `Create > Query Design`, then either build the query in the GUI or write/paste a SQL statement into the SQL View. Then click "Save", or just close the query and Access will ask if you want to save it.